# Insert sometext after first h3 in content

Tags: posts, single

I try to change something my wordpress page. I'm always writing contect with h3 tag but mutiple like each post 3 times 3h.

I want to add some text after first h3 tag.

```
function add_content_after_h3($content){
    if (is_single()) {
        $div = '<div>sometext</div>';
        $content = preg_replace('/(<\/h3>)/i', '\1'.$div, $content);
    }

    return $content[0];
}

add_filter('the_content', 'add_content_after_h3');
```

But this code not working  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note returning `$content[0];` when `!is_single()` you'll get non-exist errors.

---

You can accomplish what you're after with somthing like:

```
add_filter('the_content', function ($content){
    if (!is_single()) return $content;
    $div = "";
    return preg_replace('/<\/h3>/i', "</h3>".$div, $content, 1);
});
```

note the third parameter of [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is the limit, setting to `1` will restrict the replace to the first match.

Comment: if i want put something not after before do you have some idea for this ?

Comment: for before? then `preg_replace('/<h3/i', $div."<h3", $content, 1);`